# How do I access a module configuration from a service?

Tags: 8, configuration, symfony-services

I have a module configuration.

#### modulename.config.yml

```yaml
modulename:
  core_address: 107.101.xx.yy
  core_port: 153759
  core_user: superuser
  core_pass: superpass
```

I have a service.

#### modulename.service.yml

```yaml
services:
    modulename.my_service:
        class: Drupal\modulename\group\MyService
```

#### MyService.php

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\modulename\group\MyService.
 */
 
namespace Drupal\modulename\group;
 
/**
 * MyService.
 */
class MyService{

  public function __construct() { }
  
  public function getDemoValue() {
    $config =  \Drupal::config('modulename.my_service');
    $core_port = $config->get('modulename.core_port');
    return $core_port . 'asdf';
  }

}
```

`$core_port` is always empty.

How can I access a module configuration from a service it implements?

I am not sure this is relevant, but `getDemoValue()` is called from different a module.

```php
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\anothermodulename\Controller\MyForm.
 */
 
namespace Drupal\anothermodulename\Controller;
 
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Component\Utility\UrlHelper;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

/**
 * MyForm.
 */
class MyForm extends FormBase {

  protected $demoService;
  
  /**
   * Class constructor.
   */
  public function __construct($demoService) {
    $this->demoService = $demoService;
  }
  
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container) {
    return new static(
      $container->get('modulename.my_service')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() { /** nothing interesting here **/ }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    /** nothing interesting here **/
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function validateForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state){ /** nothing interesting here **/ }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    // Display result.
    foreach ($form_state->getValues() as $key => $value) {
      drupal_set_message($key . ': ' . $value . '  ' . $this->demoService->getDemoValue()); // i try to print here but didn't happend
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Your config file seems strange to me. The schema name is 'module.config' and that is what you should use in calls to $config->get(). You probably do not need or want 'modulename' in the config schema file content. Look at language.negotiation.yml language.schema.yml and language_negotiation_url_prefixes_update() or a full example.

Comment: @cilefen i dont have schema - only modulename.service.yml and modulename.config - do i need to have schema?

Comment: modulename.service.yml is not involved with this issue really. The problem is how you have named modulename.config.yml and the keys within it. A schema is necessary in order to have any tests and integration with the configuration system.

Comment: $config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('modulename.config') loads the entire configuration, then ->get() retrieves individual values. Read over my answer and the suggestions and example I referenced. Also see a module I work on: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/mathjax/tree/

Answer (score 5):

Use `$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('modulename.config')`.

And so on...

```
$core_port = $config->get('core_port');
$config->set('core_port', 8888)->save();
```

modulename.config.yml should be more like:

```
core_address: 107.101.xx.yy
core_port: 153759
core_user: superuser
core_pass: superpass
```

Comment: do you mind to explain to me why i should put: arguments: ['@config.factory']?

Comment: and it throw me error: "Service::__construct() must implement interface Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactoryInterface, none given,"

Comment: edited the answer...

Comment: See also http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/164713/how-do-i-update-the-configuration-of-a-module?rq=1

Comment: i did return $config->get('modulename.core_port'); and it return nothing

Comment: In your example, you should pass 'modulename' to getEditable(). Then you could $config->get('core_port');

Answer (score 3):

To read the variables (configs) you'd do this:

```
$config = \Drupal::config('modulename.my_service');

$core_port = $config->get('modulename.core_port');
```

To write to the variables (configs) you'd do this:

// Set and save new message value.

```
$config = \Drupal::service('config.factory')->getEditable('modulename.my_service');
$config->set('modulename.core_port', 153760)->save();
```

There's an example you can look at in the core module aggregator.

It has a settings form at /core/modules/aggregator/src/Form/SettingsForm.php

and then it adds a route to access the settings form:

```
aggregator.admin_settings:
  path: '/admin/config/services/aggregator/settings'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\aggregator\Form\SettingsForm'
    _title: 'Feed aggregator settings'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer news feeds'
```

You could pretty much copy the form into your module and change the variables to match your config.

Generally you'll want to add the config in your service constructor.

```
namespace Drupal\modulename;

/**
 * Example Service with config.
 */
class MyService {


  /**
   * Drupal's settings manager.
   */
  protected $settings;

  /**
   * Constructor.
   */
  public function __construct() {
    $this->settings = \Drupal::config('modulename.my_service');
  }

}
```

Then you'd access the variables like this:

```
$this->settings->get('modulename.core_port');
```

Comment: I am not sure that config will be editable.

Comment: $this->settings->get('modulename.core_port'); return nothing

Comment: did you try this?

$config = \Drupal::config('modulename.my_service');

$core_port = $config->get('modulename.core_port');

Comment: Also, keep in mind, you may need to reinstall your module with the config.  You cannot add it after the fact.

Comment: yes just try reinstall the module and still return empty but no error

Comment: i update my question

Comment: I think you need to reinstall your config.  You can check if it's installed at /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export

Answer (score 1):

Given the code shown in the question, there are two errors in `MyService::getDemoValue()`.

- Since the configuration filename is *modulename.config.yml*, the configuration object should be created with `\Drupal::config('modulename.config')`, not `\Drupal::config('modulename.my_service')` which would instead work when the configuration filename is *modulename.my_service.yml*
- Since none of the configuration values has a name that starts with *modulename.*, the configuration values should be read with (for example) `$config->get('core_port')`, not `$config->get('modulename.core_port')`

That is the code to read a configuration object. To alter the configuration values and save them, `\Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('modulename.config')` should be used instead of `\Drupal::config('modulename.config')`. In this case, setting *core_port* to 888 would be achieved using code similar to the following one.

```php
$config = \Drupal::configFactory()->getEditable('modulename.config');
$config->set('core_port', 8888)
  ->save();
```

As a side note, Drupal services should use the dependency injection container instead of requiring any Drupal service to the `\Drupal` class. That is described in [Services and Dependency Injection Container](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.api.php/group/container/9.4.x).